# react-select: Automatically suggest "other" option when you have no options for the search

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, html-select, react-select

I have a searchable dropdown field on my form, where the user does the research and selects normally.

What I need is if he types an option that does not exist, suggest the option "other" for him to select.

The "other" option already exists, I just don't know how to automatically suggest it.

I've seen about `noOptionsMessage`, but it's not useful for me, I need you to suggest the option automatically.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a props called `filterOption` to customize how you want your option filtered when the user types in the input, but it can only filter a single option and lacks the context of other options.

Because of that, to show the "other" option when no option available, you have to:

- Disable the default option filter so it doesn't mess with your custom filter.
- Control the options state.
- Filter out the options as the user type and update the options state.

Below is an example to demonstrate what I meant:

```js
import Select, { createFilter } from "react-select";

const filterOption = createFilter({});

const allOptions = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];
const otherOption = { value: "other", label: "Other" };

export default function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(allOptions);
  const filterAllOptions = (rawInput: string) => {
    const filteredOptions = allOptions.filter((o) => filterOption(o, rawInput));

    if (filteredOptions.length === 0) {
      filteredOptions.push(otherOption);
    }

    setOptions(filteredOptions);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      filterOption={() => true} // disable the default option filter
      onInputChange={(e) => filterAllOptions(e)}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66978600/automatically-suggest-other-option-when-have-no-options-for-the-search-in-reac]

Comment: This is awesome, thank you @NearHuscarl !
Is there a way to add the noOptionsMessage along with showing these 'other' option too?

I tried something like this -> 



`<Select
        options={options}
        filterOption={() => true}
        onInputChange={(e) => filterAllOptions(e)}
        components={{
          NoOptionsMessage: function NoOptionsMessage() {
            return <div> custom message </div>;
          },
        }}
      />`

But this doesn't show the not found message.